# Returned Recordset is closed (mysql DB accessed via ODBC in VBA)

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Long time viewer first time poster. I'm working on a database application with a front-end in Excel. Hence I am using VBA to access a MySQL database. The driver I'm using is the ODBC driver (Windows) and I have a valid connection to the database as lots of other queries function well.

What I'm trying to do is return the results from a series of SQL statements rather than trying to combine it all into one massive statement (which would probably work but be difficult to maintain/understand). I have added the flag `FLAG_MULTI_STATEMENTS = 67108864` to the connection string which suppressed driver syntax errors.

But now when I run the following:

```
queryDB.Open SQLquery, conn
```

The `recordset (queryDB)` remains closed with no apparent error. The sql statement can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/rzm7raer).

I may be generating errors that aren't being returned to VBA so any help here would be much appreciated.

**NOTE**: The sql statements work as I can paste that statement into `phpMyAdmin` and it returns the correct (non-empty) results. I don't know if the statements specifically are the problem but perhaps the use of `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...` or the use of multiple statements in general.

Also I guess that the driver may be trying to return a result for each sql statement and VBA is only getting the first or something...

**EDIT**: the sql statement for future reference.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpOrders AS
SELECT
o.customerName,
SUM(o.Sales) AS Sales,
SUM(TotalFobCost + TotalLandedCost + TotalLocalCost + TotalCmtCost) AS TotalCost,
YEAR(o.deliveryDate) AS YEAR,
MONTH(o.deliveryDate) AS MONTH
FROM devere_costing.orders_fixed_extras AS o
WHERE o.orderApproved = TRUE
AND o.orderCanceled = FALSE
AND o.deliveryDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-31'
GROUP BY customerName, YEAR, MONTH
ORDER BY YEAR ASC, MONTH ASC, customerName ASC;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpProj AS
SELECT p.customerName,
   IF(p.MONTH > 9, p.YEAR, p.YEAR - 1) AS TrueYear,
   1 + ((p.MONTH + 2) MOD 12) AS TrueMonth,
   SUM(p.actualSalesInvoiced) AS salesInvoiced,
   SUM(p.budget) AS budget
FROM devere_costing.sales_projection_data AS p
GROUP BY p.customerName, p.YEAR, p.MONTH
HAVING TrueYear BETWEEN YEAR('2014-01-01') AND YEAR('2014-03-31')
AND TrueMonth BETWEEN MONTH('2014-01-01') AND MONTH('2014-03-31');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpLeft AS
SELECT
IF(o.customerName IS NULL, p.customerName, o.customerName) AS customerName,
p.budget AS TotalBudget,
o.Sales AS Sales,
p.salesInvoiced,
0 AS varianceToBudget,
o.TotalCost,
0 AS directMargin,
0 AS directMarginPercent,
IF(o.YEAR IS NULL, p.TrueYear, o.YEAR) AS YEAR,
IF(o.MONTH IS NULL, p.TrueMonth, o.MONTH) AS MONTH
FROM tmpOrders AS o
LEFT JOIN tmpProj AS p
ON (o.customerName = p.customerName
AND o.YEAR = p.TrueYear
AND o.MONTH = p.TrueMonth);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpRight AS
SELECT
IF(o.customerName IS NULL, p.customerName, o.customerName) AS customerName,
p.budget AS TotalBudget,
o.Sales AS Sales,
p.salesInvoiced,
0 AS varianceToBudget,
o.TotalCost,
0 AS directMargin,
0 AS directMarginPercent,
IF(o.YEAR IS NULL, p.TrueYear, o.YEAR) AS YEAR,
IF(o.MONTH IS NULL, p.TrueMonth, o.MONTH) AS MONTH
FROM tmpOrders AS o
RIGHT JOIN tmpProj AS p
ON (o.customerName = p.customerName
AND o.YEAR = p.TrueYear
AND o.MONTH = p.TrueMonth);

(SELECT * FROM tmpLeft) UNION DISTINCT (SELECT * FROM tmpRight);
```

I have answered my own question!

The secret lies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

So I was right in that there was more than one recordset returned. I just had to iterate through them to find the data that I want. The collection isn't indexed so you have to search through each one. In my case every sql statement does not return a recordset (that's why my recordset remained closed when I tried to open it). The only exception is the last sql statement which returns records.  My loop looks like:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = queryDB(Sql)

' Loop through returned recordsets to find the data
Do
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
            ' we have an open recordset.  This means that the final select statement
            ' has returned this data.
            Exit Do
        Else
            ' Otherwise iterate through to the next recordset
            Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No recordset returned by sql statement"
        GoTo ExitCode
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Fairly nice first question! Your query should be included here instead of at pastebin though, so that people don't have to leave this site to figure out what it is you're asking. (It's only 50 or so lines, so it is easily within limits here.) (The other problems is that if the link to pastebin is unavailable for some reason, your question loses most of its context, making it meaningless to future readers.) You should [edit] and add it here instead. The [faq] has more information about asking questions here.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I had posted my sql to pastebin on purpose.  For the reasons you outlined.  I didn't want it to be hanging around forever!

Comment: However I'll edit the post as suggested since I have had a multitude of help from the posts of others on this site and on second look there isn't anything in the sql that I'd consider confidential :-)

Comment: If you post it here, you should intend on it remaining. Once it's posted here, it's public property. The [faq] mentions that anything posted is covered by the `Creative Commons license`, meaning that once it's posted here it's publicly available. If you don't want it available to the public, don't post it here. :-) Once you do, it may stay; if you delete it, that can be undone by users/mods here.

Comment: To help us out, please post your answer as an answer instead of as an update to your question. This helps future readers identify solved problems. Thank you.

Comment: +1 Good job on finding an answer yourself. As @PieterGeerkens mentioned, please post a solution and mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from the question body:

I have answered my own question!

The secret lies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

So I was right in that there was more than one recordset returned. I just had to iterate through them to find the data that I want. The collection isn't indexed so you have to search through each one. In my case every sql statement does not return a recordset (that's why my recordset remained closed when I tried to open it). The only exception is the last sql statement which returns records.  My loop looks like:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = queryDB(Sql)

' Loop through returned recordsets to find the data
Do
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
            ' we have an open recordset.  This means that the final select statement
            ' has returned this data.
            Exit Do
        Else
            ' Otherwise iterate through to the next recordset
            Set rs = rs.NextRecordset
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No recordset returned by sql statement"
        GoTo ExitCode
    End If
Loop
```